# "constructorParametersDownlevelTransform is not a function" in Angular

Tags: angular-cli

I had to run an "npm audit fix" on my project and from there after all "ng serve", I get the following error:

ERROR in TypeError: tooling_1.constructorParametersDownlevelTransform is not a function

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Thank you!

**SOLUTION:**

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.9
```

Comment: Any luck with this.. updated to angular 9 and this started happening to me!

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I just got same error. If you are using Angular 9 in your app check version of @angular-devkit/build-angular. I had version 0.1000.0 which I assume is intended for Angular v10. Probably got there by running [ncu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) I just downgraded on 0.9xxx.x and this error message is not showing anymore.

To fix this issue just *downgrade* `angular-devkit/build-angular`:

```sh
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.9
```

Comment: Thanks man! It worked for me.

npm install @ angular-devkit / build-angular @ 0.901.9

Comment: So what's the workaround for those that want/need to mitigate the `minimist` npm audit vulnerability?

Comment: Turns out they [angular-cli team] released the same vulnerability fix to the 9-lts branch as well, so one can run `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.10` to fix the error from the OP and the `minimist` security vulnerability.

Comment: I have the following.     "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1000.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.4",
Does it means also the @angular-devkit/architect should be downgraded?

Comment: @Louie Miranda Yes, @angular-devkit/build-angular to ~0.901.12 and @angular-devkit/architect to ~0.901.12

Comment: It is a know bug with npm cli: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/726

Comment: Find latest @angular-devkit/build-angular package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular?activeTab=versions

Comment: It's strange - I had a working project that was throwing errors during publishing. I decided to rebuild it from scratch with the same package.json file. It was using 0.1001.7. But then I got this error when I ran it. Changing the build as suggested fixed it, but how was it working before?